# Reactjs snippets not working in Visual code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs framework,Right now i am trying to use "snippets",For example i want if i type "RFCE" then react functional component export code should display, Actually "ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets" extension already installed in my "vs code" and i also downgrade version of current "snippet" but still not working

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have tried uppercase letters, try using lowercase letters and also try other shortcuts like "rafce". If not try restating you code editor.